E: Unable to locate package xscreensaver Ubuntu Studio 24.10
I hope everything is well. I have been trying to install xscreensaver from command line but I keep getting the same error, "E: Unable to locate package xscreensaver". I checked Ubuntu packages and it looks like there are packages available for my version of Ubuntu, 24.10. I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Did you enable the "universe" repository? see How do I enable the "Universe" repository?

yes I did. It's enabled.

I'd check your software sources, and ensure your machine software lists are up to date (ie. apt update and ensure there are no warnings, errors or missing lines).  The package xscreensaver is there so you likely have a source issue on your machine.

ok yeah, thank you. I'll check again to be sure.

One of my software sources was unchecked, in software sources. stupid me, lol.
